# Servicestack UserAuth Persistence using Nhibernate (using ServiceStack.Authentication.NHibernate)

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, servicestack

I'm trying to use the ServiceStack IUserAuthRepository implementation for Nhibernate.
I have registered `NHibernateUserAuthRepository` in my service IOC container but I don't know how to tell Nhibernate to map the `AuthUser` and roles to database table.

My mapping happens when the container instanciates `ISessionFactory` (using FluentNhibernate).

Here's AppHost code:

```
container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

container.Register<IDatabaseFactory>(c => new Oracle10DatabaseFactory(_DomainAssembly, _DomainAssemblyName,
                                                            c.Resolve<ConfigurationParameters>()));
// Register EventPublisher
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<EventPublisher, IEventPublisher>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<EventPublisherInterceptor, IInterceptor>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);

// Register Session & UnitOfWork
container.Register<NHibernate.ISession>(item =>
container.Resolve<IDatabaseFactory>().SessionFactory.OpenSession(new EventPublisherInterceptor(container.Resolve<IEventPublisher>())))
            .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);

container.Register<IUnitOfWork>(item => new UnitOfWork(container.Resolve<NHibernate.ISession>())).ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request);

Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[] { new CredentialsAuthProvider() }));
```

Here's the `Oracle10DatabaseFactory` constructor:

```
public Oracle10DatabaseFactory(Assembly assembly, string namespace, ConfigurationParameters parameters)
{
    var fileCache = new ConfigurationFileCache(assembly, parameters.PathToConfigurationFolder);
    var config = fileCache.LoadConfigurationFromFile();
    if (config == null)
    {                    
        var mapping = AutoMap.Assembly(assembly, new MappingConfiguration(new List<string>() { namespace }))
                    .Conventions.Add<ReferenceIndexConvention>()
                    .Conventions.Add<GuidIndexConvention>()
                    .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<MappingConfiguration>();


        this.sessionFactory =
                        Fluently.Configure()
                        .Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10.ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ZetesMobility_DataAccess_Connectionstring_Oracle"))
                            .UseReflectionOptimizer())


                        .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings.Add(mapping)) //.Add(baseMapping)
                        .CurrentSessionContext("web")
                        .ExposeConfiguration(c => c.BuildSchema(NHibernateExtensions.RecreateSchema()))
                        .ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("hbm2ddl.keywords", "auto-quote"))
                        .ExposeConfiguration(fileCache.SaveConfigurationToFile)
                        .BuildSessionFactory();

        config = fileCache.LoadConfigurationFromFile();
        this.sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    else
    {
        this.sessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

How do I add the Authentication classes to mapping configuration?

Many Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Fluently.Config(), the section Mappings(m -> m..., you need to tell FluentNhibernate to include the mappings in the package, like so:

```
            .Mappings(m =>
                m.FluentMappings
                    .AddFromAssemblyOf<UserAuthPersistenceDto>())
```

Yours should probably end up looking something like

```
            .Mappings(m =>
            {
                m.AutoMappings.Add(mapping);
                m.FluentMappings
                    .AddFromAssemblyOf<UserAuthPersistenceDto>();
            })
```

Comment: Now I'm getting Nhibernate exception "No session bound to the current context" when I'm trying to create default user. userRepository.GetUserAuthByUserName("admin") fails.

Comment: how/where are you opening your session (ISessionFactory.OpenSession())?

Comment: I'm trying to look into it and it weird because the code in GitHub is different than the Api that came with the nuget package. The  public NHibernateUserAuthRepository constructor takes 'ISessionFactory' but the code in GitHub is  public NHibernateUserAuthRepository(INHibernateSessionProvider sessionProvider). I'm having difficulty then to understand where the problem is.

Comment: I figured your class should call ISessionFactory.OpenSession() since it takes the dfactory in the constructor

Comment: The code in Github is quite recent, and hasn't been deployed as Nugets yet as far as I know (I'm not sure if/when this will happen). Your code: container.Resolve<IDatabaseFactory>().SessionFactory.OpenSession(new EventPublisherInterceptor(container.Resolve<IEventPublisher>())))
            .ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.Request); When is the ISession being opened? The UserAuthRepository requires the session to be opened, by someone else, before it is used. Does that make sense?

Comment: Session is opend when IUnityOfWork is resolved (which is basically calling OpenSession and then BeginTransaction). Problem is this ISession is never passed to UserAuthRepository, only ISessionFactory is sent in the constructor.

Comment: The Repo can't take an ISession, because the session may not have been opened when the container creates the repo, in which case it would be null. That's why it takes an ISessionFactory. In other codebaes, the way I get around this is to require Func<Isession>